# changing user password in mysql, check old password matches and make new password compulsory?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

can someone please help, i have this change password script that allows a user to change their password.

at the moment it lets the user change their password despite what they put in the old password box. can someone please show me how i can get it to check that the old password matches with that stored in 'ptb_users.password' ?

Also it currently lets a user set their password to nothing, is there a way i can make the enw password and confirm password fields compulsory?

Thanks.

```
<?php
require_once("session.php"); 
require_once("functions.php");
require('_config/connection.php');
?>
<?php 

session_start();

include '_config/connection.php'; 


$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM ptb_users WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND password = '".$password."'");
if(!$result) 
{ 
echo "The username you entered does not exist or old password didn't match"; 
} 
else
{
     $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET password='$newpassword' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].""); 
}
if($sql) 
{ 
    echo "Thank You. Your Password has been successfully changed."; 
}
?>
```

Comment: MD5 is *broken* for hashing passwords. Please use a more secure password-hashing function.

Comment: oh the same question by the same user... what a surprise ;)

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving passwords and checking the match against query, you may use the answer suggested by @hexacyanide.

To get the password field from mysql  to update password you need to change

`mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET password='$newpassword'`
to
`mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET password='".$newpassword."'`

Comment: thanks but updating the password is working fine, it just wont check the old password, and im not sure how to do this.

Comment: Try `echo`ing the variables $password, and $oldpassword = $result['password']; and check how they differ. Or does $result['password'] give a blank value?

Comment: Else the last variable to look for errors would be your - $_SESSION['user_id']